# What does it mean in Java when a method or constructor parameter is preceded by @Json(name="something")?

Tags: java, json, methods, parameters, constructor

I came across some code that I am trying to analyze. There is a class that has a constructor that looks something like this:

```
public Thing(@Json(name = "var1") String str, @Json(name = "var2") String str2) {
        this.instanceVar1 = str;
        this.instanceVar2 = str2;
}
```

I have tried looking it up, but I can't really find anything that answers the following question:

What does it mean in Java when a function or constructor parameter is preceded by `@Json(name="something")`?

This reminds me of how form data gets a name property in HTML/JavaScript. Even so, what would a snippet like the code above imply? Would the above code imply that there is a server somewhere, and the `String str` is being sent to that server as JSON data, with the target of this data being some endpoint with the name "var1"?

Alternatively, does this imply that some server endpoint with the name "var1" is actually the one sending the value of `str` to this constructor?

Please help me out with this.

Comment: It's called an [annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/basics.html). It is information for some tool, like a JSON parser, to work with your code. In this case it indicates to the JSON parser which JSON values need to be bound to which parameters of the constructor of `Thing`.

Comment: This is called an "annotation" in java. Many different types of such annotations exist, you can even implement your own. The idea is to influence the compilation process. This specific annotation _probably_ (depends on where that definition actually is imported from) means that this method can be used to create a value for a json object property. You should be able to pull up the annotations documentation by setting the cursor on it and jumping to its source (implementation) from there (how depends on the IDE you are using, for IntelliJ that would be CTRL-B).